# Android slider theme secondary color is not changed why?

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a range slider as below:

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
        android:id="@+id/priceSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"

        android:theme="@style/Myslider"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="100.0"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:thumbColor="@color/themecolor2"

        app:thumbRadius="8dp"
        app:values="@array/initial_slider_values" />
```

This slider has a style as below:

```
    <style name="Myslider" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
 
    
    <item name="colorPrimary">#c0c0c0</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>

    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/purple_700</item>
</style>
```

The slider takes the line color as primary color (colorPrimay), but the line between the 2 thumbs of the slider is not the colorSecondary specified in the style, it is the colorPrimary but darker,

why doesn't the slider take the secondary color from the style ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot control** the **two lines** on your graphic **separately**.

But with `ThemeOverlay.Slider` it is possible to change the color [for both(!)] without changing the whole `app:theme` color like `colorPrimary`.

Therefore add this snippet of code to your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="Rslider" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Slider">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.Slider</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.Slider" parent="">
        <!-- change the line color -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#304FFE</item>
    </style>
```

And finally apply the `@style` to your `layout` that contains the `RangeSlider`:

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
        android:id="@+id/priceSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/Rslider"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="100.0"/>
        ...
```

Wish I had better news, but `MaterialDesign` decided to clue both of the line types together with a fixed relation between each other in terms of color coding.